# React warning message: export app was not found

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm trying to learn React, and my React app stopped working.  On screen, I see a "server error" message.

Getting the below message in the terminal:

```
WARNING in ./src/renderers/dom.js 5:51-54
export 'App' (imported as 'App') was not found in 'components/App' (possible exports: default)
```

Still trying to understand how to debug issues like this, so I figured it's in the App.js file.  Here is how it looks:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Game from './Game';

const StarMatch = () => {
  const [gameId, setGameId] = useState(1);
  return <Game key={gameId} startNewGame={() => setGameId(gameId + 1)}/>;
}

export default StarMatch;
```

I thought it was because I was exporting StarMatch, so I changed it to App, but the whole page went down.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The error says you have code that has an `import` statement that's trying to import something from `components/App`  that isn't exported by that file, in `dom.js` on line 5. So what's on that line?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - There is nothing on line 5, but on line 4, there is this:  import { App } from 'components/App';

Comment: Remember to [put that in your post](/help/how-to-ask). You can only use the `import { ... }` syntax if the file you're importing from exports _exactly_ the names inside your curly braces, so if you only have a default export, you can't use curly braces in your import statement. Just as refresher, give the MDN docs on [importing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and [exporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) a quick (re)read.

Answer (score 0):

import StarMatch it will works you have to

```js
import StarMatch From './components/app'
```